# Purposes of Serialization

Tags: c#, serialization

I know serialization is a way to convert object into byte codes but what are purposes of this mechanism? Could it be used for example to save game state? (by serializing objects of map, player etc.)

Comment: Here's an MSDN sample using serialization to save game state: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203924.aspx. But don't use serialization to save game state IMO. Go with a lightweight database or indexed file implementation. This'll make your saves and loads faster, safer, and more testable than serializing to arbitrary files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are 4 reasons.

1. If you have two machines that are running the same code, and they need to communicate, an easy way is for one machine to build an object with information that it would like to transmit, and then serialize that object to the other machine. It's not the best method for communication, but it gets the job done.
2. If you want to store the state of a particular operation in a database, it can be easily serialized to a byte array, and stored in the database for later retrieval.
3. If you need an exact replica of an Object, and don't want to go to the trouble of writing your own specialized clone() class, simply serializing the object to a byte array, and then de-serializing it to another object achieves this goal.
4. Really just an application of the above, but sometimes an object takes 10 minutes to build, but would only take 10 seconds to de-serialize. So, rather than hold onto the giant object in memory, just cache it out to a file via serialization, and read it in later when it's needed.

Comment: I would be careful about serializing objects to a database.  I've seen nightmare compat problems - IMHO, it's better to decompose data into neutral relational data...

Comment: bryanmac is correct, seralization can potentially be VERY costly and should not be used without outstanding reason.

Comment: @bryanmac That depends on the serialization. If you use a well defined serialization format then this can work well. For example BSON using by mongodb.

Comment: @CodeInChaos - yeah it can be done if you're careful and seal the objects.  Note its just not the serialization - the object you're serializing better not change over major versions.  It's at minimum a painful upgrade process.

Answer (score 3):

> In computer science, in the context of data storage and transmission,
>   serialization is the process of converting a data structure or object
>   state into a format that can be stored (for example, in a file or
>   memory buffer, or transmitted across a network connection link) and
>   "resurrected" later in the same or another computer environment.

The output format of serialization is not always byte array, it can be XML, JSON, Simple text or any other format that can describe fully or partially the state of a given object.

The applications of this process are countless.

- The save/Load features are most of the time done using serialization.
- Web Services use XML/JSon serialization to transport data between
  componnents.
- Binary serialization can be used to transport object data through the network.
- Undo/Redo features also use serialization/deserialization to save old
  states of objects altough there are other methods.

Basically, serialization is used to store single data objects which state need to be retrieved later on.

Answer (score 2):

It's so objects can be persisted or transported.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ay27kt9(v=vs.71).aspx

> Serialization is the process of converting the state of an object into
>   a form that can be ***persisted or transported***. The complement of
>   serialization is deserialization, which converts a stream into an
>   object. Together, these processes allow data to be easily stored and
>   transferred.

Answer (score 2):

you often need to serialize objects, that is to say "save" in a form that will replenish later, or transmitting them over a network. This may be the preference of the user, the state of the application, a document, a command sent to a service, etc ...

You have link here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/7ay27kt9.aspx

Answer (score 2):

It essentially allows you to save the state of any object, so that an identical instance (object) can be 'brought back to life.' I.E. all instance variables are saved. So yes, using it to save a player, his stats, inventory, and so on are all great examples of the use of serialization.

Please keep in mind however, when you serialize an object, all objects referenced by the serialized object are serialized as well. And all other objects referenced by any of those referenced objects are serialized too. And so on, and so on. Thus, for serialization to work without failing, any potential objects that might be tied to a serialized object must be serializable as well.

Also be aware that static variables are NOT saved. Additionally, instance variables that you don't wish to be saved can be marked as *transient*.

Comment: The semantics of serialization depend on the serializer. Your answer seems to assume that `BinaryFormatter` is used.

Comment: My answer is more based on the experience I have with serialization in Java. I wasn't aware that C#/++ had different mechanisms for serialization. After a bit of reading it looks like serialization in C offers a greater level of control over the entire process than some of the other languages. +1 for pointing that out.